# How to concat variables in apache

Tags: apache, environment-variables, concatenation, mod-auth-openidc

I'm working with apache module mod_auth_openidc. and i'm trying to concat some variables in order to send it to my application.

```
OIDCScope "profile email openid offline_access"
OIDCRemoteUserClaim  sub


<Location "/app2">
  AuthType openid-connect
  Require valid-user
  ProxyPass   "http://192.168.10.237/myapp"
  ProxyPassReverse  "http://192.168.10.237/myapp"

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule .* - [E=PROXY_USER:%{LA-U:REMOTE_USER}] 
  RequestHeader set REMOTE_USER  %{PROXY_USER}e

</Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

My application display the HTTP header attributs 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imguur.com/SHOea.png)

The purpose is to concat "sub" and "email" values and put them together in REMOTE_USER variable.

any siggestions please ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
RequestHeader set REMOTE_USER  "%{PROXY_USER}e:%{OIDC_CLAIM_email}e"
```

since the email claim - if it exists - will have been propagated in the `OIDC_CLAIM_email` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks ! i tried this : RewriteRule .* - [E=PROXY_USER:%{HTTP:OIDC_CLAIM_email}]
 and it works